# Expected Conditions intermittently fails with error : TypeError: find_element() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having this strange issue with Selenium and was looking for a little assistance. I am using Expected Conditions to verify the presence of an element.

The issue is that sometimes it works well but sometimes it throws the following error:

```
File "selenium_func_call.py", line 327, in is_element_clickable
  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(element)
File "python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 71, in until
  value = method(self._driver)
File "python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py", line 318, in __call__
  element = visibility_of_element_located(self.locator)(driver)
File "python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py", line 139, in __call__
  return _element_if_visible(_find_element(driver, self.locator))
File "python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py", line 440, in _find_element
  return driver.find_element(*by)
TypeError: find_element() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

My call to 'element_to_be_clickable()' is correct. I am passing a tuple.
I figured it was the length of my xpath or something but that did not lead anywhere.
I added some traces to expected_conditions.py to verify if I am passing the correct arguments.

> Call to Expected Conditions

```
element = EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, element_xpath))
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(element)
```

Output from expected_conditions.py

This works:

> inside _find_element
>
> by = ('xpath', "//span[contains(text(), 'SERVICES')]/../../..")

These don't:

> inside _find_element
>
> by = ('xpath', "//div[text() = ' STORAGE']/../div[2]/div[contains(@class, 'ls-add-icon ')]")
>
> inside _find_element
>
> by = ('xpath', "//input[@name = 'id' and @value = 'Mint_Choco_Chip']/../../../../../div/div/div[text() = ' STORAGE']/../div[2]/div[contains(@class, 'ls-add-icon ')]")

Any advice on what I am doing wrong would be lovely

Comment: until() takes an function which is usually an expectedcondition... so something like "element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, element_xpath))" ... (sorry, not familiar with Python so my syntax might be wrong there...)

Comment: I was able to make it work by calling it as :
'WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath).is_displayed())'

It's not foolproof and doesn't cover all my use cases but works for now.